# CakePHP controller not receiving data

Tags: cakephp, post, var-dump

When I post form data I'm "var_dump"-ing it back to see what happens.
The form in my app is quite complex, I have data for 5 different models in it, and it goes 3 levels "deep".

Service data for example is structired like this:

```
data[Service][0][name]
data[Service][1][name]
and so on...
```

If I input only one service, everything works fine. But if I post a form with 2+ services, the controller doesnt even get the data.

When I dump it with `var_dump($this->request->data);` I get absolutely nothing...
Why could this be happening, where should I check for errors, there is nothing in apache, php or CakePHP error log...

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, but in CakePHP it is better to use `debug()` than `var_dump()`. It will render the variable nicely, show which line you've called the method from and won't output anything if occidentally left in when you switch to production mode.

Comment: You are right, and thank you, but this doesnt really help me much :P

Comment: I would encourage you to check out and install this Debug plugin... It will make your debugging a whole lot easier.. https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit